# Is this possible generate a CLI script from a configured Wildfly?

Tags: command-line-interface, wildfly-10

I'm trying to create a CLI script to setup my Wildfly servers (like [this](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/10.x/ejb-multi-server/install-domain.cli)) in domain mode.

It will be amazing if was possible generate this script from an already configured Wildfly. Is this possible? I can't find any mention of this possibility in the official docs.

If is not possible, is there some tip to help in this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any utilities for that, though it is an interesting idea. It may be possible to write a utility, but you may run into some issues the order in which resources need to be added.

However in WildFly 10 the profile resource has a `clone` operation. You could create a standard profile and clone it.

```
/profile=full:clone(to-profile=new-profile)
```